# Unable to run Cypress Test with Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am integrating Cypress Test with Gitlab CI. But when I am running the pipeline, I came up with these issues. Please find the screenshot below and help me with the possible solution for this.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the content of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` in question?? Makes it easy to help.

Comment: Sure Amir..I will attach .gitlab-ci.yml in a while.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue relate to use cypress on docker.

In this thread https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/350 you some fixes to avoid the crashes

just make sure if you are using docker or kubernetes executors

This problem doesn't happen if you use the shell executor, but in this case, you need to install the cypress locally in the server